# Why this regular expression pattern matches even an extra character in string?

Tags: python, regex

It is becoming hard for me to learn regular expressions, see the following python regular expression code snippet.

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "demo"
>>> re.search("d?mo",str)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00B65330>
```

In the above example, why it is returning the matching object, even it is not?

I know, symbol '?' means it will match either 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding character, but

From the above example,

```
1.'d' is matched with 'd'
2.'m' is matched with 'm'
3.'o' is matched with 'o'
```

But with which character 'e' is matched? Accoding to my understanding, only 'dmo' or 'mo' have to be matched with the given pattern, but why 'demo'.

If I want to match only 'dmo' or 'mo', what is the correct pattern?

Comment: Don't name a variable `str` because you will mask the built-in [str function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your are doing `re.search` instead of `re.match`. If you want to match the whole string, you have to do:

```
re.match("d?mo$",str)
```

Alternatively, you can also do:

```
re.search("^d?mo$",str)
```

to achieve a similar effect

Comment: Could you please let me know the difference between match and search methods?

Comment: @RajeshKumar, `match` only searches from the start of the string.

Comment: With which character 'e' is matched ?

Comment: @RajeshKumar, None. With `search`, the regex matches 0 d's followed by mo so infact it matches `'mo'` only. Since it is `search` instead of `match`, it matches since `search` isn't required to match from the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

`re.search('R', str)` is effectively the same as `re.match('.*R', str)` for regexes `R`.

So you have (effectively... ignoring newlines)

```
re.match(".*d?mo", "demo")
```

where the `.*` matches `"de"`, the `d?` matches `""` and the `mo` matches `"mo"`.

---

You can check this with a capturing group:

```
re.search("(d?mo)", "demo").group(0)
#>>> 'mo'
```

The `d?` matches nothing, as it's optional.